# Select the highest number in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a trading site. Users will post some price, $100, $120 for certain products. And I wanted to display highest price for that product, which means current highest price will replace the previous highest price. Tables of mysql is:

```
user_email //The user who gives price for the product
product//The product name
price//The prices that users posted
chosen//it will be 1 if it is highest otherwise 0
```

What I wanted to do is that if a user posted $100 for, for example, a book and it is currently highest price (chosen is one for this user) and site displays it. Another user posts $120 for that book and it is now highest price (chosen is 1) and for the previous user's chosen is 0. I could not figure out how to compare prices for certain products and change all of the lower prices chosen 0 for that product. How can i do this?  Sorry i am new:(

Comment: I have more than one chosen 1 because I could not pick the highest price:(

Comment: A database is not like a spreadsheet. It doesn't work to update all records when one changes. You probably want to derive the answer whenever you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MAX function from MySQL to get the highest number of a colomn. Example :

```
    SELECT MAX(field) FROM `table_name`
```

You just need to add WHERE and it will confine the search fields.

After, you update everything else with something like this

```
    UPDATE `table_name` SET `field` = 0 WHERE `product` = "X" AND `id` != Y
```

X will be the product ID and Y will be the ID from the first query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do you,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT price FROM table_name ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Using the order by clause will get you the highest price available, now store it in a variable like so,

```
$q -> execute();
$highest = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now change all the other users' price to zero,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE table_name SET price = 0 WHERE price != ?");
$q -> execute(array($highest));
```

Now this will eliminate the need for the chosen column in your database, as you only need the highest price for a bid, which can easily be found using the opposite of the above query with another parameter for the BID ID.

This example is using PDO which I highly suggest if you are making a trading site, I hope this was what you wanted to achieve,

Happy coding,

Comment: I think you need to add `DESC` to the end of the select query, and probably be good to add `LIMIT 1` after that.